# Update manager seems to have moved off screen and is lost from visibilty

Tags: 11.10, update-manager

One day, when I clicked on the update manager launcher, I could no longer see the application.

It seems as though it's moved off screen or is forever minimized. How can I get to it?

I can alt+tab to it, but when I select it, nothing happens (I just see the previous window I was on).

I tried to alt+space to see if I could move it, but the window doesn't take focus so I can't get it to it.

I've tried rebooting. I can also right click on the launcher and install updates, but I just can't see what it's doing.

Anyone have suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check to see if it was in another workspace?

Comment: If you kill the process then restart it, is it still off the screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like [bug 877444](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/877444).  If you want to track progress on the problem, I suggest you subscribe to that bug report.

You can work around the problem in two ways:

1. Right click on the update manager icon in the launcher and pick the `Install All Available Updates` menu item if you just want to install updates.
2. Rick click on the update manager icon in the launcher and choose `Quit`.  Then start the program again manually.  It should now be visible again.

Answer (score 0):

There is an item on the "power off" menu (top-right where you shutdown) calling the update manager the same way it was before (not hidden with only a progress bar on the icon as it is on 11.10).